# Insertion Sort of uint16_t halfwords?

Tags: sorting, assembly, arm

This is the first code for sorting whole signed words (`int32_t`):
[image: original int32 sort]

I tried to change it to sort `uint16_t` unsigned halfwords.  I'm almost done the code but something is missing. The problem is the sort, the architecture is ARM (in ARM mode, not Thumb); this is what I have done until now:

```
sort:   STMFD   SP!,{R4-R6,LR}
        MOV     R2,#1   //for (unsigned i = 1;
L1:     CMP     R2,R1
        BHS     L4      //                     i < toSort.size();
        MOV     R3,R2   //      for (unsigned j = i
L2:     SUBS    R3,R3,#1//                          - 1;          --j)
        BLO     L3      //                               j != -1;
        ADD     R6,R0,R3,LSL #2
        LDRH    R4,[R6]
        LDRH    R5,[R6,#2]
        CMP     R5,R4   //              if (toSort[j+1] < toSort[j])
        STRHT   R4,[R6,#2]
        STRHT   R5,[R6] //                      swap(toSort[j], toSort[j+1]);
        BLT     L2     
L3:     ADD     R2,R2,#1//              else break;               ++i)
     B       L1      
L4:     LDMFD   SP!,{R4-R6,PC}
```

```cpp
void insertionSort(vector<int>& toSort) 
{                                       
        for (int i = 1; i < toSort.size(); ++i)
                for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; --j)
                        if (toSort[j+1] < toSort[j])
                                swap(toSort[j], toSort[j+1]);
                        else
                                break; 
} */ This is the code that should be in assembly
```

Comment: Do not post pictures of code.  Instead, [edit] your question and add your code as text.  Also, I don't know why you have removed the comments from the code, but it's definitely not helpful in answering your question to have uncommented code.

Comment: @fuz here i pasted it with comments

Comment: Cool!  That looks a lot better.  Can you describe what is missing?  Perhaps make an example of some sample input, the output you expect and what output you get instead.  Try to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: Why are you using `STRHT` but `LDRH` and not `LDRHT`.

Comment: That is doing the swap before testing the condition of `[j+1] < [j]`.  Have you tried using a debugger on this?

Comment: @ErikEidt hm i dont know really because when i use ldrh and strh the numbers are not sorted

Comment: @fuz so i dont input anything it is in server and i need to just make changes but when i do ldrh and strh the result is not sorted

Comment: @hedgehoga `strht` is not an instruction you should be using.  `strh` is the right one.  Can you provide a pair of input and output to illustrate a case where the algorithm doesn't sort correctly?  Try to make it as simple as possible.  Also, have you used a debugger to trace the program's execution?

Comment: @fuz i didnt debug it because i dont know how to do it on assembly and also i have only this things make TYPE=uint16_t SIZE=размер and env PATH= sortst, i can only open sortst and sort but sort is what i pasted already

Comment: What do you mean "do"?  And what do you mean "from 32bits to 16bits"?  Is there 32-bit data somewhere that you're converting (truncating?) to 16-bit?  Also, if you want to describe this in C terms, you'll want `vector<unsigned short>&`.  Also, most std::vector implementations hold 3 pointers: start, end-of-allocation, end-of-in-use.  But it seems your asm function actually takes `sort(unsigned short *arr, size_t len)` since you expect pointer and length to already be in separate registers, not in memory pointed-to by `r0` like you'd get for taking a `std::vector` by reference.

Comment: Also, strangely you use signed `BLT` instead of `BLO` in your inner loop, even though your comments describe it a `unsigned j`.

Comment: @fuz https://ibb.co/sg8SG44 - this one is the code what it looked like before i change it
https://ibb.co/sgQKdtM
https://ibb.co/cw3dZ9F

Comment: @PeterCordes  ibb.co/sg8SG44 - this one is the code what it looked like before i change it ibb.co/sgQKdtM ibb.co/cw3dZ9F

Comment: @ErikEidt  ibb.co/sg8SG44 - this one is the code what it looked like before i change it ibb.co/sgQKdtM ibb.co/cw3dZ9F

Comment: from my teacher i know that strh should be conditional but i dont really know what that should mean

Comment: @hedgehoga You can make any instruction conditional by attaching a condition suffix to the mnemonic.  For example, write `STRHLT` to **st**o**r**e **h**alf word if **l**ess **t**han.

Comment: None of those links answer my questions about what your question title is trying to say.  It's pretty incomprehensible to future readers who see this title in a list of search results about something they're working on.

Comment: Which architecture? Arm or Thumb?

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE ARM

Comment: @fuz I tried that but what should be the parameters in it cuz it gives bad instruction

Comment: @ErikEidt I think the program shouldnt work before the changes but after i done the changes it works but the problem is that it doesnt sort the numbers in the right way they are on random places or some of them are sorted but not all maybe these strh should be changed to something but i dont know what

Comment: @PeterCordes i changed the title as more described as possible

Comment: @hedgehoga If you have an old assembler, the menmonic could also be `STRLTH`.  Please check that.

Comment: sort:   STMFD   SP!,{R4-R6,LR}
            MOV     R2,#1   
    L1:     CMP     R2,R1
            BHS     L4
            MOV     R3,R2 
    L2:     SUBS    R3,R3,#1
            BLO     L3
            ADD     R6,R0,R3,LSL #1
            LDRH    R4,[R6]
            LDRH    R5,[R6,#2]
            CMP     R5,R4
            STRH    R4,[R6,#2]
            STRH    R5,[R6]
            BLT     L2
    L3:     ADD     R2,R2,#1
            B       L1
    L4:     LDMFD   SP!,{R4-R6,PC}
i changed it to this and the result is this https://ibb.co/j4sc1Dv

Comment: That title sounds like you're supposed to write a sort that reads a `uint32_t` array and writes a sorted `uint16_t` array.  But you're not doing that, you're sorting a `uint16_t` array in-place.  Or are you describing it that way because on ARM you have to use zero- or sign-extending loads and then 32-bit compares?

Comment: @PeterCordes no so i have inssort to make in assembly but the first code that was given to me is for 32 bits(words) i have to change it so it can work for 16bits(halfwords)

Comment: That fact would be more relevant if your question showed the original code, but you don't.  Although I guess that might explain why you have `strht` (conditional full-word-store, on "higher-than") instead of conditional half-word store.  Or wait a minute, ARM unsigned "higher" is `hi` not `ht`.  https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0204/j/Chdhcfbc.  GAS won't assemble `strht` in ARM mode, but it will in Thumb mode depending on CPU options, like for cortex-a53.

Comment: @PeterCordes In this link there is the first code ibb.co/sg8SG44

Comment: Your link isn't clickable, and it's not mentioned in your question.  [edit] your question if you want to improve it.

Comment: @PeterCordes I need store command for halfword

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239889/discussion-between-hedgehoga-and-peter-cordes).

Comment: @PeterCordes, the `strht` is not a conditional store it is a "privileged" store (this store checks to see if in priv mode and if so operates as if in user mode).  I believe that is was intended to have been a regular, conditional store instead, but was wrong even in the original.

Comment: @ErikEidt: Yeah, thanks, just found https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0406/cb/Application-Level-Architecture/Instruction-Details/Alphabetical-list-of-instructions/STRHT myself.  The code block in this question won't assembler for me as either ARM or Thumb, with pretty obvious error messages about STRHT in ARM mode.  I see the original code in the image used `strlt`, a conditional word-store.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes i need store function conditional something for halfwords(16 bits)

Comment: @ErikEidt My instructor told me it should be conditional not regular strh

Comment: Yes, people keep telling you that.

Comment: @ErikEidt yes but the problem is that i tried few times different solutions and still it doesnt work properly

Comment: Did you try what fuz suggested?

Comment: @ErikEidt It gives error bad instruction maybe i am putting wrong parameters?

Comment: @fuz  thank you thank you it worked, also thanks to everyone who gave a minute from his time for my problem

Comment: @fuz I done it myself so thanks everyone for the help i wish u all good luck and good health in these times. Wish u all the best!

Comment: @fuz i have a friend that has a little bit like my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70260497/stupid-sort-of-uint16-t-halfwords can u check it, if u have some suggestion, of course if u want only :D

Comment: @fuz i'm really sorry i wont anymore please forgive me for my ignorance

Answer (score 2):

Based on the original, your changes look reasonable, except that you need to shift #1 instead of #2 in the `ADD     R6,R0,R3,LSL #2`.  This is because the #2 is for 4 byte integers, #1 would be for 2 byte integers.  This is a shift amount and the shift count reflects the power of 2 by which you want to scale the index.  For 4 byte integers we want to multiply/scale by 4, which is 2<sup>2</sup>, whereas for 2 byte integers we want to multiply/scale by 2, which is 2<sup>1</sup>.  When shifting in binary, the number of bits to shift multiplies by that power of 2.

However, I find it very difficult to believe that the original insertion sort actually works.  (Did you test it independently of your modifications?)

In particular, as I have said, "the swap is happening before the condition test", and, further your instruction told you that the `strh` should be conditional, another way of describing the same problem.

So, that code is not following the insertion sort as described in comment.

The intent of the if-statement within the inner loop is to detect when insertion point has been reached, and immediately stop the inner loop.  Or else if the insertion point hasn't been reached, then swap elements and continue the inner loop.

That code is instead doing the following:

```
swap ( toSort[j], toSort[j+1 );
if ( toSort[j+1] >= toSort[j] )
    break;
```

With that being at the end of the inner loop.

Or more specifically:

```
conditionCodes = toSort[j+1] < toSort[j];
swap ( toSort[j], toSort[j+1 );
if ( conditionCodes is less than )
    continue;
break;
```

The effect of this is that when the proper stopping point is reached, it will stop, but will also have unwantedly swapped two elements.

You can stop that swap from happening in the last iteration, either by changing the flow of control so that those store instructions are not executed, or as @fuz says, on ARM you can make those store instructions themselves each conditional, which is probably what the original author intended, given how far apart the `CMP` and `BLT` are.  However, the conditional operation of those stores was lost somewhere along the way.

Comment: The original sort was using `strlt`, a conditional word-store.  So that makes the swap conditional, using the same condition as the still-present `blt`.   Exiting the inner loop the first time you don't swap seems wrong for Bubble Sort, though, and this is comparing pairs, not doing an insertion sort.  (Or is it only starting from the top of the sorted region, in which case bubbling is a valid but inefficient way?)  Is that what you meant by the original sort probably not working?  Hmm, looks like the 16-bit version also forgot to change the indexing, it should be `LSL #1` not #2.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I though I looked at the original having the `strht`, but I guess I was mistaken.