# Stupid Sort of uint16_t halfwords?

Tags: sorting, assembly, arm

This is the first code for sorting whole signed words (int32_t):

```
sort:   SUB     R1,R1,#1        //--n           void StupidSort(int a[], int n)
        ADD     R12,R0,#4       //нач.адрес+4   {
        ADD     R1,R0,R1,LSL#2  //краен адрес       int tmp, i = 0;
L1:     LDR     R3,[R0]         //*a                do {
        LDR     R2,[R0,#4]!     //*++a ___              if (a[i] > a[i+1]) {
        CMP     R3,R2           //        \                 tmp = a[i+1];
        BLE     L2              //         \                a[i+1] = a[i];
        STMDA   R0,{R2,R3}      //          \               a[i] = tmp;
        CMP     R0,R12          //           \              if (i) i--;
        SUBHI   R0,R0,#8        //            \___      } else i++;
L2:     CMP     R0,R1           //                  } while (i < n - 1);
        BLT     L1              //              }
        BX      LR
```

This is what I have done until now:

```
sort:   SUB     R1,R1,#1        //--n           void StupidSort(int a[], int n)
                ADD     R12,R0,#2       //нач.адрес+4   {
                ADD     R1,R0,R1,LSL#1  //краен адрес       int tmp, i = 0;
        L1:     LDRH    R3,[R0]         //*a                do {
                LDRH    R2,[R0,#2]!     //*++a ___              if (a[i] > a[i+1]) {
                CMP     R3,R2           //        \                 tmp = a[i+1];
                BLE     L2              //         \                a[i+1] = a[i];
                STRH    R2,[R0,#2]
                STRH    R3,[R0]         //          \               a[i] = tmp;
                CMP     R0,R12          //           \              if (i) i--;
                SUBHI   R0,R0,#4        //            \___      } else i++;
        L2:     CMP     R0,R1           //                  } while (i < n - 1);
                BLT     L1              //              }
                BX      LR
```

I tried to change it to sort uint16_t unsigned halfwords. I'm almost done but something is
missing in the code. The problem is the sort, the architecture is ARM (in ARM mode, not
Thumb);Also i don't know what the sign ! behind LDRH function do also i think on ldrd r3 and
r2 should rotate their places.

Comment: @AlexF i mean that something is missing because when i compile it and then run it, it shows 10 numbers that are exactly the same

Comment: @AlexF and also in the end of the second ldrh there is ! and i dont know what it is used for

Comment: Please don't do stupid sorts. Code smart. But the `!` stands for pre-indexing. `ldrh r2,[r0, #2]!` updates `r0 = r0 + 2` before memory access. `ldrh r2, [r0], #2` would post-update, btw.

Comment: Very similar question to [Insertion Sort of uint16\_t halfwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70236946), although the 32-bit sort there was using conditional predicated stores, instead of a branch to skip an `stm`.  (And was using `ldm` for the loads; fun fact: you can't use *both* LDM and STM for an efficient swap because there's no way to have the register list in a different order; it's a bitmap.)

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen do you think i should change the places of r3 and r2 in ldrh

Comment: Why are you doing `a++`?  The C code doesn't have that.

Comment: @ErikEidt where?

Comment: sort:   SUB     R1,R1,#1
        ADD     R12,R0,#2
        ADD     R1,R0,R1,LSL#1
L1:     LDRH    R2,[R0]
        LDRH    R3,[R0],#2
        CMP     R3,R2
        BLE     L2
        STRH    R2,[R0,#2]
        STRH    R3,[R0]
        CMP     R0,R12
        SUBHI   R0,R0,#4 
L2:     CMP     R0,R1
        BLT     L1
        BX      LR
Now the numbers are not the same but they are not sorted

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen the solution didnt work that u suggested

Comment: @PeterCordes so it shouldnt be strh?

Comment: It is really awkward to work with assembly code and "matching" C code, when the assembly significantly diverges from the C code.  Here the assembly has been optimized to use pointers instead of array indexing: `i` does not even exist in the assembly code, and neither does `a`, they have been folded together into a pointer, `R0`.  Even `n` has been turned from an integer into a pointer, `R1`.  A better approach for learning and teaching here would have been to do that optimization in the C version first, since C supports mutable pointers.

Comment: @ErikEidt yeah its kinda annoying

Comment: @PeterCordes if i use ldrh so i cant use strh in this problem?

Comment: No, that's the opposite of what I said.  And there is no load-multiple or store-multiple for half-words, so you have to use ldrh / strh, no option to use a single instruction for a pair of operations.  (Unless you did a bitfield-insert to set up for a word store.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes but still using them i dont get the right result, ther are not sorted

Comment: It's possible to write buggy programs even when using the right instructions.  This looks like one pass of the inner loop of Bubble Sort, with no outer loop around it, so as [Aki already told you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70260497/stupid-sort-of-uint16-t-halfwords#comment124218219_70261421), it won't fully sort.

Comment: @PeterCordes ah i see i will wait for someone if has any suggestions and will try to do it

Answer (score 1):

The `!` stands for pre-increment, exactly as in the comment `*++a`.
Thus, the offset #2 is added to the base `r0` before memory access, but also the register `r0` is updated.

```
L1:     LDRH    R3,[R0]         //*a                do {
        LDRH    R2,[R0,#2]!     //*++a ___              if (a[i] > a[i+1]) {
        CMP     R3,R2           //        \                 tmp = a[i+1];
        BLE     L2              //         \                a[i+1] = a[i];
        STRH    R2,[R0,#-2]     // ***      \
        STRH    R3,[R0]         // ***       \               a[i] = tmp;
        CMP     R0,R12          //            \              if (i) i--;
        SUBHI   R0,R0,#4        //             \___     } else i++;
L2:     CMP     R0,R1           //                  } while (i < n - 1);
```

The sections marked with `***` have been modified to compensate the effect of `*++a`;

Generally there are probably better ways to implement an insertion or bubble sort; this algorithms e.g. reads the same element in the next round which was written on the previous iteration. Also it would probably make more sense to use conditional swap/move instead of explicit branch.

The corresponding 32-bit code writes the swapped values with a clever (obfuscated) way with  `STMDA   R0,{R2,R3}`, which relies on the `R2, R3` having been read in the order of `R3, R2`. This instruction stands for STore Multiple, Decrement After, writing R2 to `R0 - 4` and R3 to `R0`. But because that variant is not available for 16-bit registers, one needs to write R2 to `R0 - 2` and R3 to `R0`.

Comment: _"The ! stands for pre-increment"_. Nitpick: The `!` stands for write-back. The pre-increment (or pre-_index_) part is given by having an offset inside the brackets (i.e. `,#2]` as opposed to `],#2`).

Comment: It's write-back yes, but also `],#2` is write-back. Thus it makes also sense to differentiate these as _pre-increment_, _indexed_ and _post-increment_.

Comment: @chaikataaaaa: I made a mistake indeed in the order of the write back of `r2, r3`. The way it was in my original post, didn't actually swap the order. Now that part is fixed as well.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen I think also it shouble be #-2 instead of -#2

Comment: What you should expect from this code and from the original code is that the output has all the same elements as the input. Also this code will only partially sort the data. Not fully. It requires at most N-1 passes to sort data with this kind of sorting algorithm.

Comment: Well, I stand corrected. `StupidSort` as implemented in C indeed seems to implement a generic sort in slightly obfuscated way. My last edit was wrong -- `subhi r0,r0, #4` needs to have `#4`, because it needs to undo the `++a` done in `LDRH    R2,[R0,#2]!`.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen what do u think about the part sort: is the parameters right?

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen your code has worked thank you very much

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen thank you very much also to everyone else who spared a minute to help, thank you again aki wish u all the best to you and your family, and be safe in this Covid time

Comment: @chaikataaaaa, no problem. I too learned something in the process. I'll start deleting those comments, that are no longer useful for future readers -- also the standard procedure is to accept the answers...